# floating from right to left HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

In [this](https://codepen.io/whusterj/pres/bdYKop) example the item is floating bottto-top, how can I change it to float right and left?

I have tried to play with the numbers but I don't get the desired result

```css
.floating {
  animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

@keyframes floating {
  from {
    transform: translate(90, 8px);
  }
  35% {
    transform: translate(70, 8px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(50, -8px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="floating" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: rgb(200,200,200);"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated fiddle: https://codepen.io/Nisharg/pen/bzwZvB

simply add value

`65%  { transform: translate(15px, 0);`

```css
.floating {  
  animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

@keyframes floating {
    from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    65%  { transform: translate(15px, 0); }
    to   { transform: translate(0, 0); }    
}
```

```html
<div class="floating" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: rgb(200,200,200);"></div>
```

Comment: don't forgot to consider up-vote and check this answer as best answer for you by clicking on right arrow, thanks!